# Ito product rule

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

Stochastic Differential Equation
$dS(t) = rS(t)(α − S(t))dt + σS(t)dW(t), S(0) = x.$
where W(t) is a standard Brownian motion and r, α, σ are positive constants.
I have no idea why this question need ito product rule.
Show by using the product rule that the following process is a closed-form solution
of the above Stochastic Differential Equation

$$S(t)=\frac{\exp\big\{(r\alpha-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)t+\sigma W(t)\big\}}{\frac{1}{x}+r\int_0^t\exp\big\{(r\alpha-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)s+\sigma W(s)\big\}\ ds}$$

I have no idea why this question need ito product rule.

My thought is let $f(Z)=\frac{Z}{(1/x+r\int z\ ds)}$
$dS(t)=df(z(t))=fz(z(t))dz(t)+fzz(z(t))dz(t)dz(t)$, but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$X=\exp\big\{ct+\sigma W(t)\big\}$$
and

$$Y=\left(\frac{1}{x}+r\int_0^t\exp\big\{cs+\sigma W(s)\big\}\ ds\right)^{-1}.$$

We have

$$dX=cXdt+\sigma XdW_{t}+\frac{\sigma^{2}}{2}Xdt=X(r\alpha )dt+\sigma XdW_{t}$$

and

$$dY=-Y^{2}rX_{t}dt.$$

The Itô product rule says

$$dS_{t}=d(XY)=XdY+YdX+d\langle X,Y\rangle$$

$$=X(-Y^{2}rX_{t})dt+Y(X(r\alpha )dt+\sigma XdW_{t})+0$$

$$=\left((XY)r\alpha-r(XY)^{2}\right)dt+XY\sigma dW_{t}$$
$$=\left(S_{t}r\alpha-rS_{t}^{2}\right)dt+S_{t}\sigma dW_{t}.$$